# Putting content to frontpage in Joomla 1.5

Tags: database, joomla, frontpage

What should be changed in Joomla's database to put content to the frontpage?

I've got a great deal of articles and making it by hand would take a lot of time. So I'm looking for an automatic way.

Answer (score 1):

The frontpage of Joomla is not a specific component. It can be any component, but defaults to the com_frontpage component in Joomla1.0 and com_content component in Joomla1.5.

Most likely what you want is to just export all your articles to the database. Take a look at your Joomla database to get an idea of it's structure.

You have jos_content and jos_sections and jos_categories which you want to insert data into.

Most importantly though is jos_content. Write a PHP file that takes each article, and just inserts that article into the jos_content table.